# In terraform using Azure, is it possible to create a key vault secret and reference that secret in the same file on the same run?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I am attempting to generate a random username and password, store them in key vault and then immediately (after they are stored) retrieve them and use them as variables in the sql server creation.

Considering this code:

```
resource "random_string" "username" {
  length = 24
  special = true
  override_special = "%@!"
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 24
  special = true
  override_special = "%@!"
}

# # Create KeyVault Secret
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-1-username" {
  name         = "sql-server-1-username"
  value        = random_string.username.result
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tags = merge(local.common_tags, tomap({"type" = "key-vault-secret-username"}), tomap({"resource" = azurerm_mssql_server.sql-server_1.name}))
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.key_vault]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-1-password" {
  name         = "sql-server-1-password"
  value        = random_password.password.result
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tags = merge(local.common_tags, tomap({"type" = "key-vault-secret-password"}), tomap({"resource" = azurerm_mssql_server.sql-server_1.name}))
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.key_vault]
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-server-1-username" {
  name = "sql-server-1-username"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-server-1-password" {
  name = "sql-server-1-password"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sql-server_1" {
  name = "${local.resource-name-prefix}-sql-server-1"
  resource_group_name = local.resource-group-name
  location            = var.resource-location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-server-1-username.value
  administrator_login_password = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-server-1-password.value
  tags = merge(local.common_tags, tomap({"type" = "mssql-server"}))
}
```

When running this via terraform I get:

```
│ Error: KeyVault Secret "sql-server-1-username" <<<KEY VAULT>>> does not exist
│ 
│   with data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-server-1-username,
│   on sql-server.tf line 31, in data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-server-1-username":
│   31: data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-server-1-username" {
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: KeyVault Secret "sql-server-1-password" <<<KEY VAULT>>> does not exist
│ 
│   with data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-server-1-password,
│   on sql-server.tf line 36, in data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-server-1-password":
│   36: data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-server-1-password" {
│
```

and I understand because at run time terraform is trying to evaluate that secret but it hasn't been created.

My question is, is there a way to define a value, store it as a key vault secret and then upon completion of that azurerm_key_vault_secret resource being complete, retrieve that value?

As a work around, I've put lifecycle blocks with ignore_change for the username and password values on both the key vault secret resources and the sql server. That *should* give me the same values in key vault being used as the username/password for the sql server, but that feels like the wrong solution.

What would be the better way?

Comment: Why are using data when you have the actual resource there?

Comment: What about using the "random resources" directly and save them later?

Comment: There is no such thing as `data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-1-username` in your code.

Comment: @Marcin You're right. I copied the wrong code. I've updated it.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda That's what I ended up doing. I was trying to limit the places I have to put lifecycle blocks to just the azurerm_key_vault_secret definitions and not have one in the sql server definition too. Now I just have multiple lifecycle blocks. I guess it doesn't really matter, I just wanted to ensure I was using whatever ended up in the key vault.

Comment: If you put a secret in the vault, you know what you put in, can't you just use that value directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.*` in `azurerm_mssql_server` it doesn't consider dependency , so instead of creating the ***keyvault secret*** it creates the ***sqlserver*** first as it doesn't have any dependencies on the resources created by the file thats the reason you get the error .

For solution , If you are creating the ***keyvault secret*** in the same file then instead of using ***data blocks*** , you can directly reference the value for ***administrator_login*** and ***administrator_login_password*** with `azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-1-username.value` and `azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-1-password.value`.

**Your Code will be like below:**

```
resource "random_string" "username" {
  length = 24
  special = true
  override_special = "%@!"
}

resource "random_password" "password" {
  length = 24
  special = true
  override_special = "%@!"
}

# # Create KeyVault Secret
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-1-username" {
  name         = "sql-server-1-username"
  value        = random_string.username.result
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tags = merge(local.common_tags, tomap({"type" = "key-vault-secret-username"}), tomap({"resource" = azurerm_mssql_server.sql-server_1.name}))
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault.key_vault]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "sql-1-password" {
  name         = "sql-server-1-password"
  value        = random_password.password.result
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.key_vault.id
  tags = merge(local.common_tags, tomap({"type" = "key-vault-secret-password"}), tomap({"resource" = azurerm_mssql_server.sql-server_1.name}))
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-1-username]
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sql-server_1" {
  name = "${local.resource-name-prefix}-sql-server-1"
  resource_group_name = local.resource-group-name
  location            = var.resource-location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-1-username.value
  administrator_login_password = azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-1-password.value
  tags = merge(local.common_tags, tomap({"type" = "mssql-server"}))
  depends_on = [azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-1-password]
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. This is what I initially tried to do but I get a cycle error and that made me try other methods.
```
│ Error: Cycle: azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-1-username, azurerm_mssql_server.sql-server_1, azurerm_key_vault_secret.sql-1-password
```

Comment: @JasonShive , may i know the version of azurerm and terraform you are using?

Comment: Also , i edited the code with depends on in 2nd secret.. it will be created after the 1st secret is created and then added a depends on in mssql as well

Comment: can you try the new updated code

Comment: The depends on was something I had tried as well and it still throws a cycle error but I was overcomplicating the process and your solution is much more efficient.  However, I was using version 1.0.5 of the binary and 2.69.0 provider. This was because our azure government cloud runs failed on newer versions, but I suspect this to be resolved in the future.